# Intercept method request and change parameter value

Tags: c#

I was able to create the following example:

**ObservableClass**

```
public class ObservableClass : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public int DoSomething(int id, params string[] names)
    {
        return 1 + names.Length;
    }

    public int DoSomethingElse(int id, params string[] names)
    {
        return 1 + names.Length;
    }
}
```

**Interceptor**

```
public class Interceptor : RealProxy
{
    private readonly object _target;

    public Interceptor(object target) : base(target.GetType()) { _target = target; }

    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        var methodCall = msg as IMethodCallMessage;
        return methodCall != null ? HandleMethodCall(methodCall) : null;
    }

    private IMessage HandleMethodCall(IMethodCallMessage methodCall)
    {
        try
        {
            var newArgs = methodCall.InArgs;
            if (methodCall.MethodName == "DoSomething")
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < newArgs.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (methodCall.GetArgName(i) == "names")
                    {
                        newArgs[i] = new string[] { "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4" };
                    }
                }
            }
            var result = methodCall.MethodBase.Invoke(_target, newArgs);
            return new ReturnMessage(result, null, 0, methodCall.LogicalCallContext, methodCall);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException invocationException)
        {
            var exception = invocationException.InnerException;
            return new ReturnMessage(exception, methodCall);
        }
    }

    public static T Wrap<T>(T target) where T : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        return (T)new Interceptor(target).GetTransparentProxy();
    }
}
```

And calling it by:

```
var temp = Interceptor.Wrap(new ObservableClass());
var doSomethingRes = temp.DoSomething(1, "a", "b", "c");
var doSomethingElseRes = temp.DoSomethingElse(1, "a", "b", "c");
```

**Output**: doSomethingRes = 5, doSomethingElseRes = 4.

This is working, however after some research I believe that the use of the **MarshalByRefObject** and the remote **RealProxy** will be extremely expensive for my real application scenario.

I was wondering what other options (light and good performance) do I have to make something similar?

Comment: What's wring with making a decorator manually?

Comment: @DiligentKeyPresser Well,  because my idea is to make one simple "logic" instead of  a decorator per class that extends an abstract class with my "target" method. And in the future "extra" add-on "plug-ins" would not need to have another "special" decorator class.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes .net Remoting is very slow. If you need something high performing -- you can use dynamic proxies.

Castle Windsor supports [dynamic proxies](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) and [interception](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/interceptors.md) which can help you.